# リーダーモード用HTMLのガイドライン

Tags: html

スマートフォン用ブラウザの多くはWebページの記事部分のみを抜き出して読み易く表示する「リーダーモード」という機能が備わっています。他にも似たような機能を持つWebサービスとしてReadabilityやInstapaperがあります。

リーダーモードは便利ですが、ページによっては画像が表示されなかったり記事の抽出に失敗したりと、ブラウザの実装やサービスによってレンダリングがまちまちな印象です。

これらの表示をある程度統一させるためのガイドラインまたは参考資料はあるのでしょうか？

参考までに、IE11のReading Viewに関する資料は見つかりました。

- [Introducing Reading View in IE 11 - MSDN Blogs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ie/introducing-reading-view-in-ie-11)
- [Reading View Guidelines](https://web.archive.org/web/20150428121220/http://ie.microsoft.com:80/testdrive/browser/readingview/)

Answer (score 1):

stackoverflow(英語版)にAndroid Firefox のリーダーモードに関する質問がありました。
参考になるかもしれません。
[android - How is 'reader mode' in Firefox triggered? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15206695/how-is-reader-mode-in-firefox-triggered)

Comment: なるほど、Firefoxのリーダーモードの基になっているReadabilityには開発者用ガイドラインがあるようですね。 [Article Publishing Guidelines](https://www.readability.com/developers/guidelines)